# Vue.js 2 + API created with PHP microframework Slim

Tags: javascript, php, api, vue.js, slim

I'm learning how to create an API and connect it with Vue.js application.
I need to create a users' registration form. 
Is it correct if I create an API with PHP and then connect it to my Vue.js in order to register users. An API will be connected to MySQL db.

Here's my db.php class:

```
class DB {
    private $dbhost = 'localhost';
    private $dbuser = 'root';
    private $dbpass = '';
    private $dbname = 'organization';

    public function Connect() {
      $mysqli = new mysqli($this->dbhost, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpass, $this->dbname);

      if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
          echo "Не удалось подключиться к MySQL: (".$mysqli->connect_errno.") ".$mysqli->connect_error;
      }
      return $mysqli;
    }
  }
```

And this is one of routes:

```
<?php
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

$app = new \Slim\App;

$app->get('/api/customers', function(Request $request, Response $response) {
  $db = new DB();
  $db = $db->Connect();

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM workers";
  $result = $db->query($sql);

  echo json_encode($result->fetch_assoc());

  $db->close();
});
```

Comment: What did you tried? Add some code

Comment: @PieroAlberto Added some code. Will it be correct if I continue creating my API and then connect it to my Vue.js app?

Comment: Sure, but you will need to add some authentication like jwt as middleware, else its an open api ;p

Comment: @LawrenceCherone And what about sessions? How should I store them?

Comment: You dont need sessions with jwt, but if you want sessions as well just do as normal.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Could you please show me a piece of code with sessions in Vue.js?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone and using jwt as well ;) thank u

Comment: You must return a valid Response object. Don't use echo. Example: `return $response->withJson($result->fetch_assoc());`